# Final variables from once class is giving error when accessing them in subclass for a case clause of switch

Tags: java, static, switch-statement, constants, final

In Switch's case clause, only constants are allowed. When we try to access final variables from another class in to a non static method,
  by extending that another class, compile  time error is shown as to make those variables as constant (but I have already declared them as final)

```
package com.another.pack;

public class AnotherPackClass {

    public final int a=10,b=90;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public static int add(int x,int y){
        return (x+y); 
    }
}
```

In my test class I have extended above class and using those a,b variables as below

[image]

PS: If I declare a,b variables in `AnotherPackClass`  and `switchStmnt()` in  Test  class as `static` and call it in `main()`, I am able to execute the code.

But I do not want it to use so, I want to leave both of them as non static and do not call it in `main()`.

The error I am getting is "case expression must be constant expression" 
Also PS that, I have declared a,b as final . Still I am getting this error.

Please give some reason for it.

Comment: This is awfully verbose if you're just asking why case expressions have to be constant.

Comment: Why do you want them as non-static if they are truly constants, i.e. `final` with a constant expression themselves? If they can never change at runtime, all instances will have the same value, so not declaring them `static` is a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me, I'm using inner class :

```
public class AnotherPackClass {

public final int a = 10, b = 90;

class A extends AnotherPackClass {
    void switchstmt() {
        int x = 100;
        switch (x) {
        case a+b:System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AnotherPackClass().new A().switchstmt();
}

public static int add(int x, int y) {
    return (x + y);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey , thanks for quick reply. I have my Test (as class A from your example) all together in another package ,  please try moving Class A in to another package then import and extend   AnotherPackageClass ie; like this,Class A extends AnotherPackageClass.